# What Characters to allow for Usernames?

Tags: username

Each user will have a unique username as it is going to be used to link to their profile page.
As an example, in the following URL `johndoe` is the username `http://www.example.com/user/johndoe`. Are there any best practices that I need to follow? What characters should be allowed?

Comment: this is a question that has been asked many times both on this site and on other StackExchange sites.  For example, see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87366/are-there-any-valid-reasons-for-disallowing-characters-and-limiting-the-length-o.  There are plenty more posts on this topic which will show up in a simple Google search.  You have shown no effort to do any kind of research before asking the question, so it is a waste of the community's time.  Please be more considerate in the future.

Comment: @tohster What's the best maximum length for a username? Why should I limit characters (Only a-z, 0-9 & underscores) like Twitter, Google and the others do? Also, the second link that you posted is about passwords, it has nothing to do with **usernames**

Comment: @AlGallaf if a comment suggests that a post is a duplicate and the post is subsequently closed as a duplicate any comment that includes a link to that other post is automatically deleted.

Answer (score 2):

While it is mostly depends on the requirements you have, points to note are

1. Characters that conflict with the http addresses are to be omitted. Like # or /
2. Characters that may get encoded while transmitting the data must be carefully looked into. Like spaces
3. Use only ASCII characters.
4. As an observation, alphanumeric usernames of length 6/8 or more supported with underscore or period, without spaces in between is a good one to start with.